# Is it permissible in to make software application that deal with music, films, TV dramas etc or to make programming assignments for students?

Tags: halal-haram, work, software, school

I am an Android developer and working as a freelancers, normally I receive requests from clients to make them an application which deal with music or convert their music and video website to an android application. And these clients are non Muslims.

Many students from different part of word ask me to make their school or university programming assignments and projects. Some also say that they will promise that they are not going to submit it but just see the code to get help in completing their project.

Shall I entertain these types of clients or simply refuse to work for them in a polite manner?

Answer (score 1):

If you believe that Music is haram (which I and many others don't), then making something for using it will also be forbidden (minor sin).

For helping with assignment, if they promise that the assignment is not for submitting but to learn, that could be haram to them if they do submit it. If you are confident that they will use it for cheating, then it becomes a minor sin to help them do so (forbidden).

Answer (score -1):

If it doesn't go against the Sharia, then you can help them or do the job. However if it goes against the Sharia then you need to leave it brother.
I hope that was clear enough. Because you know what the Sharia states, music and dance and all such stuffs which drive us away from our Creator is not welcome and neither should we ever appreciate them. If you help them in making it, it's just like you are appreciating them and that's wrong. 
As far as assignments are concerned, I believe they are solely for study purposes, so as long as the studies don't deal with Haram stuff, like music and dance and similar, you can help them. 
Hope this helps.

Comment: Don't you think that doing assignments is helping students in cheating, and prohibited in Islam ?

Comment: As assignments are given to students to do by themselves without any help, specially paid

Answer (score -2):

If you believe Allah forbid music, any type of them than what do you mean?

You believe it's haram than, ya it deserve the fire of hell.

But, concerning the music from the western world which is a godless people, their music usually contains haram allover. There's still halal music though.

And helping student to do their assignment did you understood from the quran and hadis that it's haram. No it's not haram, what cheating!. Unless they've a 'covenant' that they will do it themself then ya, if you know that, it means you are helping them breaking their oath. ..... That will be haram.